# Media queries being stripped from gmail

Tags: email, gmail, html-email

I have a bunch of media queries for my email but they seem to be getting stripped out in gmail. Does anyone know why this is? Does gmail not support media queries?

Heres my query in case im doing something wrong

```
    @media (max-width: 500px){
      .test-table {
       display: block !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      display: none;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Gmail supports @media queries.

It will also strip a malformed style sheet or class from the head as well. If there is no class, `test-table`, it might strip the entire @media query. You did not post your code, so I cannot tell.

Try changing this:

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
```

To this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
```

Let us know if the class was missing or if changing the @media query resolves the issue.

Good luck.

Comment: Also worth posting Can I email with the few notes on Gmail's support: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media/

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, Ive triple checked for this but there doesnt seem to be anything that shouldnt be there. I have also changed the media query to what you have suggested. Could anything else cause this?

Comment: I have tested this further, In the media query i added * { padding: 500px; } and this only affected the padding of the body of the email. I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: This only happens with padding. I added a background color and it works perfectly